# starting with gtk# under monodevelop, Gdk.PixBuf issues

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I need to create C# application under Fedora 15. I have skills only for creating applications under Windows (Winforms or WPF), so I choose gtk# and monodevelop. It big change... 
I have a lot of problems. At first I wanted in monodevelop to add icon for window (Main Window - Window properties. just 1 from standard gtk icons) and in MainWindow.cs and generated.cs appeared error: cannot implicitly convert type 'Gdk.PixBuf' to 'Gdk.PixBuf'. What is that? I removed icon and this error is still there...
Next one - I wanted to add a reference, but there is just option for editing references...
I also wanted to use Glade and compile applications with 
`mcs demo.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp`
and it tells me:
`No package 'gtk-sharp' found
error CS8027: Error running pkg-config.`
Please, help me.

Comment: [The mono project has put alot of effort into its documentation and tutorials.](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp:_Hello_World)

Comment: if you didnt read my question, please DO NOT ANSWER

Comment: There are no answers currently, so perhaps *nobody* has read your question. Keep writing hostile all-caps comments though; that'll probably help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the issue with pixbuf gets from diffrent versions of gtk-sharp. Maybe you installed the plugins (from gallery) for binding other versions of gtk (2.4, 2.6, 2.8)? If so, uninstall or disable them all. Try to run your project on the gtk shipped with monodevelop. It shuld help, at least with the pixbuf issue.

Other errors you sharing here looks like the problem is not with mono or monodevelop at all. Linuxes are very chalanging for new users (i know what i'm saying - i'm quite new to linux too) so the best way for you is to install fresh copy of fedora, install then monodevelop with it's dependencies at first. Try if md is working, and then keep testing like this all the time, whenever you install anything. Stay focus all the time. And if the problems reapear you know what is going on, and where start to looking for solution. I know that's not very stylish, but it gives you some feedback and information.

Good luck!